# Building a Iterator class for linked list (Error: no matching constructor for initialization)

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

In the function "Iteratoring List::begin()" {
It has a problem " no matching constructor for initialization" for this Iteratoring(head). head is a node pointer and I built a constructor for it. I do not know what the problem is.

**List.h**

```
#include "Iteratoring.h"
struct Node {
    int data;       // value in the node
    Node *next;  //  the address of the next node

    /**************************************
            **      CONSTRUCTOR    **
    ***************************************/
    Node(int data) : data(data), next(0) {}
};
class List {
private:
    Node *head= nullptr;          // head node
    Node *tail;          // tail node
    Iteratoring begin();
public:
};
```

**List.cpp**

```
#include "List.h"

Iteratoring List::begin() {
    return Iteratoring(head);   //The error is here. no matching constructor for initialization
}
```

**Iteratoring.h**

```
#include "List.h"

class Iteratoring {
private:
    Node *current;
public:
    Iteratoring(){
        current= nullptr;
    };

    Iteratoring(Node *ptr){
        current=ptr;
    };

};
```

Comment: It's the standard circular dependency problem: The file `List.h` includes `Iteratoring.h` which includes `List.h`. You solve this by *forward declarations* (my tip is to use forward declaration of `Node` in the `Iteratoring.h` file, and remove the inclusion of `List.h`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a circular dependency issue. There's `#include "List.h"` in `Iteratoring.h`, and `#include "Iteratoring.h"` in `List.h`.

You should use [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) instead. e.g.

**Iteratoring.h**

```
class Node;
class Iteratoring {
private:
    Node *current;
public:
    Iteratoring(){
        current= nullptr;
    };

    Iteratoring(Node *ptr){
        current=ptr;
    };

};
```

Comment: Thank You. Where are you learned this? My school never teach me this.

Comment: @Mr.Java From [books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/3309790) and cppreference.com.

Comment: @Mr.Java Schools miss a lot in teaching c++ usually. It's also a question of experience.